# ByteStrings in Haskell: should I use Put or Builder?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, binary-data

I'm confused as to what the `Put` monad offers over using `Builder` directly, in `Data.Binary`. I read the [Binary Generation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/DealingWithBinaryData#Binary_generation) section of Dealing with Binary data, and it seems to assume that you should use `Put`, but it's pretty short doesn't explain why.

**Data.Binary.Put**

> The Put monad. A monad for efficiently constructing lazy bytestrings.
>
> ```
> type Put = PutM ()
> ```
>
> Put merely lifts Builder into a Writer monad, applied to ().

**Data.Binary.Builder**

> Efficient construction of lazy byte strings.

---

*What is the point of a `Writer` monad applied to `()`?*

I can see that `Put` is (a type synonym to) a monad whereas `Builder` is not, but I don't really get why `Put` would be needed.

In my case, I'm rendering a 3D scene and writing each pixel as a 3 bytes, and then adding on the PPM format's header to the beginning (will use PNG later).

`Binary` seems like it is meant to be instantiated for types that can be serialized and deserialized to and from binary data. This isn't exactly what I'm doing, but it felt natural to instantiate `Binary` for my colour type

```
instance (Binary a) => Binary (Colour a) where
    put (Colour r g b) = put r >> put g >> put b
    get = Colour <$> get <*> get <*> get
```

This makes it easy to `put` a `Colour Word8` into 24 bits. But then I also have to tack on the header, and I'm not sure how I should do that.

Is `Builder` meant to be hidden behind the scenes, or does it depend? Is the `Binary` class only for (de)serializing data, or for all binary generation purposes?

Comment: Not an answer, but you may want to take a look into using blaze-builder (and friends) rather than binary.

Comment: @TiloWiklund: I had seen that before. What's different about it? Is it more efficient?

Comment: Among other things. There's a good writeup by one of the authors here: http://lambda-view.blogspot.se/2010/11/blaze-builder-library-faster.html

Comment: The `Binary` class and its methods `Get` and `Put` are essentially for serializing and de-serializing Haskell structures. If you are working with a existing binary format it is better (in my opinion, of course) to avoid the Binary class and instead use the explicit functions like `putWord8`, `putWord32le`, etc.

Comment: @stephentetley: That was kind of what I was thinking too, but I wasn't sure… For the colours at least, it's convenient to use `Put`, and makes sense semantically too, but I don't know if I should use `Put` for everything or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all note the conceptual difference.  Builders are for efficient building of bytestring streams, while the `PutM` monad is really for serialization.  So the first question you should ask yourself is whether you are actually serializing (to answer that ask yourself whether there is a meaningful and exact opposite operation – deserialization).

In general I would go with `Builder` for the convenience it provides.  However, not the `Builder` from the *binary* package, but in fact from the *blaze-builder* package.  It's a monoid and has many predefined string generators.  It is also very composable.  Finally it's very fast and can in fact be fine-tuned.

Last but not least if you really want speed, convenience and elegant code you will want to combine this with one of the various stream processor libraries around like *conduit*, *enumerator* or *pipes*.

Answer (score 10):

> I can see that `Put` is a monad whereas `Builder` is not, but I don't really get why `Put` would be needed.

To be precise, `PutM` is the `Monad`. It's needed for convenience, and to give you fewer opportunities for errors. Writing code in monadic or applicative style is often much more convenient than carrying all the temporaries around explicitly, and with the plumbing done in the `Monad` instance, you can't accidentally use the wrong `Builder` in the middle of your function.

You can do everything you do with `PutM` using only `Builder`, but usually it's more work to write the code.

> But then I also have to tack on the header, and I'm not sure how I should do that.

I don't know the PPM format, so I have no idea how to construct the header. But after constructing it, you can simply use `putByteString` or `putLazyByteString` to tack it on.

Comment: Would you agree that `Put` is only intended for serializing and deserializing, and (for example) rendering data one-way to a binary image (as a ByteString) would be better done using just `Builder` (possibly blaze-builder), as others have said?

Comment: I'd say `put` and `get` are, but `Put` and `Get` can reasonably be used with wider scope. However, the primary intention of [binary](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary) was indeed (de)serialization of Haskell structures, so the interface was shaped for that. Thus blaze-builder may be the better choice (I've never used that, so I don't know how convenient it is to use).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure to what extent this is accurate, but my understanding has always been that the presentation of `Put` as you see it is largely an abuse of do-notation so that you can write code like this:

```
putThing :: Thing -> Put
putThing (Thing thing1 thing2) = do
  putThing1 thing1
  putThing2 thing2
```

We are not using the "essence" of `Monad` (in particular, we never bind the result of anything) but we gain a convenient and clean syntax for concatenation. However, the aesthetic advantages over the purely monoidal alternative:

```
putThing :: Thing -> Builder
putThing (Thing thing1 thing2) = mconcat [
  putThing thing1,
  putThing thing2]
```

are fairly minimal, in my view.

(Note that `Get`, by contrast, genuinely *is* a Monad and benefits from being so in clear ways).